# Opening PDB file in GROMACS on Windows using Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin

I am a first time user of GROMACS. According to this excellent tutorial (http://www.mdtutorials.com/gmx/lysozyme/01_pdb2gmx.html), I downloaded the PDB file for lyzozyme, then removed water molecules, typed in the following command on CygwinShell (with GROMACS activated).

$ gmx pdb2gmx -f 1AKI_clean.pdb -o 1AKI_processed.gro -water spce

However, I get an error saying:

In command line option -f, file 1AKI_clean.pdb does not exit or is not accessible.

Please advice where am I going wrong. Any insight would be appreciated.Thank you,
Neena

Comment: where is the file 1AKI_clean.pdb ?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, now that I transferred the file into working directory, I do not get that error anymore.